# Laravel Policies in Controller Constructor

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using a Policy Class to authorize some users(authors or admins) to update and delete records from Post Model. It is a simple CRUD. The question is: How can I make a policy check run for specifics methods at once? For example, I can use a middleware in my PostController constructor to check if user is logged, but how can I do something similar to a policy that needs parameters?

**PostController**

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
}
```

**PostPolicy**

```
class PostPolicy
{
  use HandlesAuthorization;

  public function before($user)
  {
    if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public function manage($user, $post)
  {
    return $user->id == $post->user_id;
  }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
  $this->registerPolicies();

  Gate::define('manage-post', 'App\Policies\PostPolicy@manage');
}
```

I tried this:

```
$this->middleware('can:manage-post', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
```

But it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: need to see your route definition

Answer (score 0):

I would just register the policy and use that instead of writing out an 'ability' separately.

```
can:manage,post
```

`manage` the action, `post` the Route Parameter to use for the gate (resource).

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - Authorization - Authorizing Actions - via Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-middleware)